# Table restructuring for efficiency?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, join

I am moving data from Access to SQL Server. One of the tables I'm working with has some columns like this:
ID | Date | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | Sensor3 | Sensor4 | Sensor5 | Sensor6 | Sensor7 | Sensor 8 | Sensor9

**Certain Facts:**
At any point atleast 3  of these columns would be filled.
More Sensors could be added in the future
This table in entirety has 120 columns (above is just a portion)
ID is TinyInt
Sensor data is Decimal(4,2)

When I looked at the table structure and the Nulls due to the facts above, I thought of changing it to a structure like this:

ID |Date | Sensor_NO | Data

**My question is:**
Considering I'm breaking down a huge table. This sort of table restructuring would make it much more difficult to join the individual tables because I will have to transpose the table first and then join the various tables based on ID.
Would my proposed structure going to improve efficiency to a point where it is worth the work of creating JOINS later? Would you consider such a transformation?

Comment: When joining, do you always need all the data from all the sensors for any ID? Or sometimes do you only care about sensor 1 or sensor 6 etc? Also how often do you care about the other 110+ columns? I don't think we have enough of the story here.

Comment: I would be creating a view that would mirror the current 120 column structure if I decide to use the proposed table structure. The user would always want all the data of all the sensors that have data in them and as i mentioned at any one point atleast three sensors would generate data. My proposed structure would not record sensors that do not generate data, so that helps in not recording nulls.

Comment: So are you interested in comparing the value of sensor 3 with the value if sensor 92 on the same date? You have a few things consider: 1. Which schema lends itself to getting data in and out of the database; 2. How many more records do you need to store it in normalised design? Especially considering expected growth over then next few years. 3. What does and doesn't work right now with the current design? You're talking about joins and tables in your question but I only see one table explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you can answer if the the change is worth the effort.

Yes restructuring would be marginally more efficient. The main advantage being that new sensors can be added in the future without altering your table structure. The downside is that it's harder to enforce business rules and logic.

The advantage of your current design is that if the sensor types are consistent per column you could have different data types, int, float, bit, varchar etc, whereas if you put all of your sensor values in a single column you'll need to use the lower common denominator (most likely a varchar).

Given that you're talking about sensors, I expect you will be recording over time, so you'd probably need a timestamp, and decide on what else need to be stored with the value. Quality codes? non-detects? what about the sensor type?

Comment: The sensors are of the same type so the values are always Decimal (4,2). As I mentioned earlier there are 120 columns, but the above proposed structure is a normalized version of only the Sensors ( so the columns mentioned above would be the only ones in that table). Also, you are right the data is measured with time and i have updated the question for it.